Usage of pattern for ilist command
I am trying to work with a large JSON file and I would like to print the lines with an occurrence of a any one of two particular strings.
For this I'm using ilist, for one string I can do as follows to print all lines where the term Token appears for example:
:ilist /Token

This is great but it only prints the line with the token and the token value, as expected.
Since this is a large file I'd like more context. There is another field not far from this Token called name. I'd like to print all lines with either Token or name. So I tried:
:ilist /Token|name

But it doesn't work and I get a E389: Couldn't find pattern error.
I learnt that regular expressions are a little different in vim and so I found this and tried to understand how to achieve the above, but I failed and I am now here. Can anyone help me understand how to use pattern in this context?

While :help :ilist can be used to print lines matching a given pattern, it is not really designed for that.
Combining :help :global and one of :help :list, :help :print, :help :number, :help :#, and :help :z, on the other hand, is the canonical way to do what you are trying to do. Note that :g/pattern, without a command, defaults to :print.
All you need is the correct pattern.
If you want to print lines with either token or name:
:g/\<token\>\|\<name\>

See :help \<, :help \>, and :help \|. You could probably get by without the word boundaries but it is cleaner that way.
If you want to print lines with both token and name, in that order:
:g/\<token\>.*\<name\>

If you want to print lines with both token and name, in any order:
:g/.*\<name\>\&.*\<token\>.*

If you insist on using :ilist:
:ilist token\|name


If you want to print lines with both token and name, in any order: :g/.*name\&.*token.*. See :h /\&

Answer amended.
